# SPICE Model For Voltage Reference

Tags: spice, ltspice

Anyone aware where can I find SPICE models for [MAX6126](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6126.pdf), [MAX6250](http://datasheet.eeworld.com.cn/pdf/MAXIM/10031_MAX6241.pdf) etc? I searched a lot and could not find. If anyone knows, can you please share the link/file?

Comment: Does your simulation need to account for failure cases of those references? If not, just a constant voltage source through a resistor, equivalent to the stated output impedance of each part, should do the trick. If you have multiple supply rails, and you need to, you could switch the voltage source via a switch enabled from the supply rail of interest. That would account for use-case of the reference's supply being off while the other supply rail(s) are still on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are complex devices containing many transistors and components, so any SPICE model will be a macro model, made up of voltage controlled currents sources, Current controlled current sources , Voltage controlled voltage sources etc. etc.  and the only people who can do that reasonably are the designers themselves.

Look on the Maxim website for these models, if they don't have them look to someone who second sources these parts and might have done it.  The company that is best at this is LT itself so I'd suggest seeing if there is a close match and then it would be likely that LT has these devices in the library for LTSpice.